# Transmit parameter by value or by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, parameters, pass-by-value, pass-by-const-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass by reference more expensive than pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108084/pass-by-reference-more-expensive-than-pass-by-value)

I want to know which is better, sending parameters by value or by reference in C++. I heard that there are cases where sending by value is faster than sending by reference. Which are these cases?

Thanks

Comment: When you send by value - copy of object is created (time and space consuming). So instead it is better to send by const& or &(in case if you want modify the object)

Comment: @UmNyobe Maybe here [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/). But there is also a discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108084/pass-by-reference-more-expensive-than-pass-by-value

Comment: A reference is implemented using a pointer, so if the parameter is smaller than a pointer then passing it by value may be faster.

Comment: yes, but there are cases for basic types, for example int or float where it is slower to send by reference than by value. I'd like to know which bytes does a type to have in order to be faster sending by value than reference

Comment: "I'd like to know which bytes does a type to have in order to be faster sending by value than reference". Depends more on : which assembly instructions are used to make the value available to the function and to access this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you should pass POD types by value and complex types by const reference.

That said, a good place where you pass complex types by value is where you would need a copy of the object inside the function anyway. In that case, you have two choices:

- pass the argument as a const reference and create a local copy inside the function
- pass the argument by value (the compiler creates the local copy).

The second option is generally more efficient. For an example, see the [copy&swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Answer (score 1):

The obvious case is when the parameter is equal to or smaller than a pointer in size *and trivial to copy* -- then you would pass by value. However, this is a age-old discussion and quite a long answer is required to answer it correctly for a given architecture. There are also many corner cases (e.g. RVO).

There's more to the question than speed -- semantics should be your first priority.

See also: [Is it better in C++ to pass by value or pass by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference/270435#270435)